# Groovy gradle check if file exits?

Tags: android, file, gradle, groovy

I am trying to check if a file exists on a certain path in android gradle

This is my code

```
File file = new File("../../../../releases/${version}", "${project.name}-${version}-release.aar")
            if (outputFile.name.contains("debug"))
                file = new File("../../../../releases/${version}", "${project.name}-${version}-debug.aar")
            if (file.exists()) {
                println("file found")
                throw new GradleException("Aar already exists in folder $version. Change name of folder if you want the same version")
            } else{println("file not found")
                outputFileName = file}
```

It is always falling in the else case

I have tried two methods and both of them are giving false

```
println("file exists "+ file.getAbsoluteFile().exists())
            println("file exists "+ file.exists())
```

Comment: Switch from using `new File(..blah...)` to gradle helper method `file("${project.rootDir}/releases${version}/${project.name}")`.  Much simpler to use than the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to path

```
File file = new File("${project.getRootDir()}/releases/${version}", "${project.name}-${version}-release.aar")
                if (file.exists())
                    throw new GradleException("Aar already exists in folder $version. Change name of folder if you want the same version")
```